# Seeing Moon on the 4th day (Chaturthi) of the Bhadrapada Shukla paksha(Ganesha Chaturthi)

Tags: belief, ganesha

Anyone seeing Moon on the 4th day (Chaturthi) of the Bhadrapada month would face blame and unjust criticism, its know to all Hindus but what about others across the earth.

Comment: Are you asking whether non-Hindus believe that it's bad to look at the moon on Ganesha Chaturthi?  Of course not.

Comment: My question is how would the curse effect those who unaware of it.

Comment: Insofar as such a curse exists, I think it would equally affect those who know about it and thus who do not.  But I don't think the curse has any basis in Hindu scripture, because I don't even think Ganesha Chaturthi has a basis in Hindu scripture; there's no record of Ganesha Chaturthi earlier than 500 years ago.

Comment: @pybear I agree with Keshav : The festival was celebrated as a public event since the days of Maratha King Shivaji (1630–1680). However, the public festival as celebrated in Maharashtra today, was introduced by Bhausaheb Laxman Javale in 1892 by installing first Sarvajanik (Public) Ganesh idol- Shrimant Bhausaheb Rangari Ganpati, Bhudwar Peth, in Pune. see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesh_Chaturthi

Comment: @BhavinPatel yes I agree with both hence a +1 for both but I want know about the curse,how the curse effects those who are unaware of it.

Comment: @Keshav and Bhavin - Totally agree.

Comment: @pybear you wiil know more about curse through this :  http://aravindb1982.hubpages.com/hub/Why-you-should-not-see-the-moon-on-Ganesh-Chaturthi-Story-of-the-Syamantaka-gem   --  http://ganapattibappa.blogspot.in/2012/12/lord-ganesh-story-cursing-moon.html  -----------  http://hinduism.about.com/od/lordganesha/a/Ganesha-Tales.htm

Comment: Ganesh Chaturthi does not have any basis in Scriptures?? Really?? why don't u delete that comment of urs? @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @Rickross I'm not deleting that comment because as far as I know it's correct.  If you have a scriptural reference that Ganesha was born on the date we now call Ganesha Chaturthi, I'd be happy to see it.

Answer (score 5):

The **12th Adhyaya of the 1st Khanda** of [**Ganesha Purana**(pg 83 to 88 in Hindi)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Y5Ito6ltz_LTdseF9lVUZOYW8) gives a story of Ganesha's curse to Chandrama.

A brief summary of the story is as follows:

> Once when all the gods are gathered around Brahma, Shiva Parvati were
> also there along with their two sons Kumara (Kartikeya) and Ganesha.
> Lord Shiva had a divine fruit which Ganesha and Kartikeya demanded
> together. Lord Shiva being confused asks Brahma for advice.
>
> Brahma tells him to give it to Kumara as Kumara is older in age. Lord
> Shiva does so and then the family returns home. Brahma begins to
> perform creation. Ganesha is angry with Brahma's decision and he
> plants obstacles during Brahma's creation.
>
> He finally appears before Brahma assuming a fierce form. Brahma
> trembles on seeing Ganesha's wrath. On seeing Brahma's fear at
> Ganesha's form Chandra laughs at him along with his attendants.
>
> Ganesha is furious at this mockery and curses Chandra, **"O fool, by
> mocking me thus you have shown your indecency, henceforth no one will
> see your face and those who do would reap sin."**
>
> This was problematic for the people on earth so the gods advise
> Chandra to propitiate Ganesha and ask for his forgiveness. Chandra
> does so and **Ganesha modifies the curse to apply on only one day i.e.
> Bhadrapada Shukla Chaturthi.**

The story is very clear on the curse affecting people regardless of if they know about it or if they don't know.

So yes even other people on earth who do not know about the story or curse would be affected by it.

> [image]
>
> *Translation:* On Shukla Chaturthi of Bhadrapada, **knowing or unknowingly
> if one views the moon** one is cursed with frequent/great sorrows, there
> is no doubt about this.

Comment: Is Ganesha Purana avaliable online?...

Comment: @Tezz Yes I found it in 4 parts on Scribd. It's in Hindi. I've uploaded it on Google Drive. [Part 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Y5Ito6ltz_LTdseF9lVUZOYW8) [Part 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Y5Ito6ltz_V2tYWGFjbzgzRkk) [Part 3](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Y5Ito6ltz_ZjR0MTQ1dkFfb0k) [Part 4](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Y5Ito6ltz_YThLdmtKeXYzbm8)